# What is the meaning of Bandit's Note in Donut County?

Tags: donut-county

I found this object in my Trashopedia, after completing the Raccoon HQ level.

[image: It says "Up, Left, Down, Left, Grab"]

The "Up, Left, Down, Left, Grab" made me think of the Biology Lab, but entering that sequence of commands on the buttons there doesn't seem to have any effect.

(I'm playing on iOS, if that matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering this sequence in the Biology Lab as soon as you can start pushing buttons unlocks a vault down the hall, and an achievement on most platforms. You've got the right idea, but I have heard about some inconsistency with it, so you may have to try again.

Check out this video for more information (it's from PS4, but the same principles should still apply)

Comment: I never would have figured out that you have to start in the bottom right, and bump both of the gutters first.

Comment: @JacobKrall I'm pretty sure I did this from the starting position? But I dunno, whatever works.